# Hide options of select in angular based on tab selection

Tags: angular

- I want to implement a select in which there are total four options

  There are two tabs

  if active tab is 'abc' only two select options should be visible.

  I tried the below code but it is hiding the two options for both
  tabs.

  Can anyone advise?

```
                    <select id="taxRateTypeId" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentTaxRate">
                        <option value="one">one</option>
                        <option value="two">two</option>
                        <div *ngIf="activeTab === 'abc'">
                         <option hidden value="three">three</option>
                        <option hidden value="four">four</option>
                      </div>

                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put *ngIf on the individual option elements themselves.

```
<select>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option *ngIf="activeTab === 'abc'" value="three">three</option>
  <option *ngIf="activeTab === 'abc'" value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `*ngIf` on a div you should use it on a **`ng-container`**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="activeTab === 'abc'">
     <option  value="three">three</option>
     <option value="four">four</option>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: <ng-container> is not solving,still getting hidden for both tabs

Comment: Remove the `hidden` attribute from the option elements and this approach will work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up yohosuff